# psycopg2 occasionally returns null

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, postgresql, psycopg2

So I'm using psycopg2, I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed_cache (
    feed_id int REFERENCES feeds(id) UNIQUE,
    feed_cache text NOT NULL,
    expire_date timestamp --without time zone
);
```

I'm calling the following method and query:

```
@staticmethod
def get_feed_cache(conn, feed_id):
    c = conn.cursor()
    try:
        sql = 'SELECT feed_cache FROM feed_cache WHERE feed_id=%s AND localtimestamp <= expire_date;'
        c.execute(sql, (feed_id,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result:
            conn.commit()
            return result[0]
        else:
            print 'DBSELECT.get_feed_cache: %s' % result
            print 'sql: %s' % (c.mogrify(sql, (feed_id,)))
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        c.close()
    return None
```

I've added the *else* statement to output the exact sql and result that is being executed and returned.

The get_feed_cache() method is called from a database connection thread pool. When the get_feed_cache() method is called "slowishly" (~1/sec or less) the result is returned as expected, however when called concurrently it will *occasionally* return None. I have tried multiple ways of writing this query & method.

Some observations:

1. If I remove 'AND localtimestamp <= expire_date' from the query, the query ALWAYS returns a result.
2. Executing the query rapidly in serial in psql always returns a result.
3. After reading about the fetch*() methods of psycopg's cursor class they note that the results are cached for the cursor, I'm assuming that the cache is not shared between different cursors. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#best-practices
4. I have tried using postgresql's now() and current_timestamp functions with the same results. (I am aware of the timezone aspect of now() & current_timestamp)

Conditions to note:

1. There will NEVER be a case where there is not a feed_cache value for a provided feed_id.
2. There will NEVER be a case where any value in the feed_cache table is NULL
3. While testing I have completely disabled any & all writes to this table
4. I have set the expire_date to be sufficiently far in the future for all values such that the expression 'AND localtimestamp <= expire_date' will always be true.

Here is a copy & pasted output of it returning None:

```
DBSELECT.get_feed_cache: None
sql: SELECT feed_cache FROM feed_cache WHERE feed_id=5 AND localtimestamp < expire_date;
```

Well that's pretty much it, I'm not sure what's going on. Maybe I'm making some really dumb mistake and I just don't notice it! <s>My current guess is that it has something to do with psycopg2 and perhaps the way it's caching results between cursors. If the cursors DO share the cache and the queries happen near-simultaneously then it could be possible that the first cursor fetches the result, the second cursor sees there is a cache of the same query, so it does not execute, then the first cursor closes and deletes the cache and the second cursor tries to fetch a now null/None cache.</s>*

That said, psycopg2 states that it's thread-safe for read-only queries, so unless I'm miss-interpreting their implementation of thread-safe, this shouldn't be the case.

Thank you for your time!

*After adding a thread lock for the get_feed_cache, acquiring before creating the cursor and releasing before returning, I still occasionally get a None result

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't have NULL values in the table? What does `SELECT * FROM feed_cache WHERE feed_cache IS NULL` says? I am asking this because your code seems fine and I feel there is something wrong in your data.

Comment: SELECT * FROM feed_cache WHERE feed_cache IS NULL;

    feed_id | feed_cache | expire_date 
    ---------+------------+-------------
    (0 rows)

Comment: Sorry about formatting, 0 rows were returned.

Comment: Here's a link to everything in the db. http://pastebin.com/Dwt7B84g

Comment: Okay so after looking at it I figured I would try putting the expire_date way further in the future, (a month) and everything worked perfectly. So I'm guessing it's something to do with timezones. Normally the expire_date is set to 30 minutes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have to do with the fact that the time stamps returned by `localtimestamp` or `current_timestamp` are fixed when the transaction starts, not when you run the statement.  And psycopg manages the transactions behind your back to some degree.  So you might be getting a slightly older time stamp.

You could debug this by setting `log_statement = all` in your server and then observing when the `BEGIN` statements are executed relative to your queries.

You might want to look into using a function such as `clock_timestamp()`, which updates more often per transaction.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html.